# Global.asax Changes cause Resharper to lose view references

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resharper, asp.net-mvc-5

I updated the Global.asax.cs file in an existing project by moving the RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes) function to RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes).
I also moved the RegisterGlovalFilters() and WarmUpEntityFramework() to separate files.

After moving those functions ReSharper has lost all it's references to the controllers corresponding views.  I've tried clearing ReSharpers cache, unloading/re-loading the project, cleaning the project.  It's like ReSharper is not able to read into the RegisterRoutes() function now.